# need to exclude specific values from a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two column A & B where I am getting this kind of values

```
'00100000004pZFQAA2','00300000007AurPAAS' & etc.
```

I am trying to exclude the same using (A like '%[^a-zA-Z0-9]%' OR b like '%[^a-zA-Z0-9]%') but it is still showing those values.

Please suggest how I can exclude those values without impacting other values

Comment: What values are you trying to exclude?  Please be more explicit.

Comment: Gordon Linoff @ These are the values which I am trying to exclude '00100000004pZFQAA2','00300000007AurPAAS'. These two columns contains Dates, Numbers, String values also

Comment: What is your expected result and how to get it?

Comment: Those like clauses match any string containing anything that isn't a letter or number. But those values are entirely made of letters and numbers.

Comment: Can you show us your entire SQL code?

Comment: Also, do you have 'bad' data in both col A and col B in the same row? If one of the columns is okay, but others is bad, what to do then? If you want to exclude, then change the OR to AND (assuming this is the entire `where` clause).

Answer (score 0):

These look like Salesforce ID values.  Given that you know they will all be 18 characters long and begin with a fix set of 3 characters (depending on object).  So, something like the following should be sufficient...

```
Select * 
from tableName 
where NOT 
(LEN(columnNameA) = 18 and LEFT(columnNameA,3)  in ('001', '003')) OR
(LEN(columnNameB) = 18 and LEFT(columnNameB,3)  in ('001', '003'))
```